# Rewrite assets paths in CSS/SASS/SCSS in webpack

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I'm upgrading from Webpack 4 to Webpack 5, here's my config file diff:
https://diffy.org/diff/5599db6178258

I have a CSS file assets/fonts/inter.css that contains font definitions like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style:  normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url("Inter-Thin.woff2?v=3.15") format("woff2"),
       url("Inter-Thin.woff?v=3.15") format("woff");
}
```

When this file is included in a SCSS or JS file, those `url`s used to get rewritten to `assets/fonts/Inter-Thin.woff2?v=3.15`, but are now untouched.

I tried using `resolve-url-loader` but it doesn't do anything. How do I get urls to be rewritten to the right path?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're upgrading to webpack 5.

1. either `url-loader` or `file-loader` are deprecated for webpack 5, so prefer to use the built-in [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) to replace them as they might not be compatible with the latest webpack 5
2. you can customize the output path and filename for targeted assets with [output.assetModuleFilename](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#custom-output-filename)